# How to read a comma-separated numerical string and perform various functions on it

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a column with numerical comma-separated strings, e.g., `'0,1,17,200,6,0,1'`.
I want to create new columns for the sums of those numbers (or substrings) in the strings that are **not** equal to 0.

I can use something like this to count the sum of non-zero numbers for the **whole string**:

```
df$F1 <- sapply(strsplit(df1$a, ","), function(x) length(which(x>0)))
[1] 5
```

This outputs '5' as the number of substrings in for the example string above, which is correct as the number of substrings in `'0,1,17,200,6,0,1'` is indeed 5.

The challenge, however, is to be able to **restrict the number of substrings**. For example, how can I get the the count for only the first 3 or 6 substrings in the string?

Comment: Did you try the `strsplit` function? It will give you the split results in list containing a vector for each row. Then you have to use the suitable `apply` family function to calculate all the statistics for each row.

Comment: I am using that only, as mentioned in my question, if you read it. My concern is with the length of the string I want to pick while using the strsplit function.

Comment: Can you create a small  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output based on that?

Comment: Edited my question for the better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` and backreference to cut the string to the desired length *before* you count how many substrings are > 0:

**DATA**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = "0,1,17,200,6,0,1")
df1$a <- as.character(df1$a)
```

**SOLUTION**:

First cut the string to whatever number of substrings you want--here, I'm cutting it to three numeric characters (the first two of which are followed by a comma)--and store the result in a new vector:

```
df1$a_3 <- gsub("^(\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)(.*)", "\\1", df1$a)
df1$a_3
[1] "0,1,17"
```

Now insert the new vector into your `sapply` statement to count how many substrings are greater than 0:

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$a_3, ","), function(x) length(which(x>0)))
[1] 2
```

To vary the number of substrings, vary the number of repetitions of `\\d+` in the pattern accordingly. For example, this works for 6 substrings:

```
df1$a_6 <- gsub("^(\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+,\\d+)(.*)", "\\1", df1$a)
sapply(strsplit(df1$a_6, ","), function(x) length(which(x>0)))
[1] 4
```

**EDIT** TO ACCOUNT FOR NEW SET OF QUESTIONS:

To compute the maximum value of substrings > 0, exemplified here for `df1$a`, the string as a whole (for the restricted strings, just use the relevant vector accordingly, e.g., `df1$a_3`, `df1$a_6` etc.):
First split the string using `strsplit`, then unlist the resulting list using `unlist`, and finally convert the resulting vector from character to numeric, storing the result in a vector, e.g., `string_a`:

```
string_a <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(df1$a, ",")))
string_a
[1]   0   1  17 200   6   0   1
```

On that vector you can perform all sorts of functions, including `max` for the maximum value, and `sum` for the sum of the values:

```
max(string_a)
[1] 200

sum(string_a)
[1] 225
```

Re the number of values that are equal to 0, adjust your `sapply` statement by setting `x == 0`:

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$a, ","), function(x) length(which(x == 0)))
[1] 2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, how can I get the sum and max of all the substrings as well, along with the count of 'non-zero' substrings?

Comment: This seems to be a set of new questions. Can you please accept my previous answer (if it did answer your question) before I deal with the new questions?

Comment: @Vjain Hi, plz see EDIT